# Append div multiple times using JavaScript on DOM Loaded

Tags: javascript, parent-child, appendchild

I want to append the HTML child_element div multiple times as defined on variables inside the parent_element using Javascript on DOM Load.

Desire Output:

```
<div class="parent_element">
   <div class = "child_element">
   <div class = "child_element">
   <div class = "child_element">
   <div class = "child_element">
   <div class = "child_element">
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want this to happen on click event or when the DOM will load it will be there say for 5 times or 6 times?

Comment: @TBA I want this when the DOM is loaded.

Comment: @PrabichShakya you may, if you wish, make minor edits to your question to add the clarifications requested. It's then slightly easier for people to provide answers without needing to read through the comments. As long as you don't change anything critical which would invalidate answers already given. Also consider [removing fluff](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions). Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a child node object and append it to the parent node in loop. Since you have multiple child nodes to be appended you can use [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment.)

```
const parentNode = document.createElement('div');
parentNode.classList.add('parent_element');
const childNode = document.createElement('div');
childNode.classList.add('child_element');
const fragment = new DocumentFragment();

for(let i=0; i<[*no_of_times_you_want_child_node*]; i++) {
    fragment.appendChild(childNode.cloneNode(true));
}

// finally append dom fragment to parent
parentNode.appendChild(fragment);
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want the number of children to be defined by an attribute "variables inside the parent_element"

```html
<div class="parent" children="5"></div>
<script>
const parentEl = document.querySelector(".parent");
const numOfChildren = +parentEl.getAttribute("children");
const fragment = new DocumentFragment();
for (let i=0; i<numOfChildren; i++) {
    const childEl = document.createElement("div");
    childEl.classList.add("child");
    fragment.appendChild(childEl);
}
parentEl.append(fragment);
</script>
```

The basic process is:

1. Get a reference to the parent element using the class selector
2. Retrieve the number of children you want from the attribute named `children`. This is a string value so the `+` will convert it to a number
3. Loop through the creation of a new element on the DOM adding the desired class name before [appending the child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append).

Edit: As per pilchard's suggestion I've merged in [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment.) from [abhishek khandait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69695976/1447419)'s answer.

Comment: A nice clean answer, but consider accumulating the new elements and only appending once after the loop. Either in an array and then spread into append(), or in a document.fragment

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically add a new div element using jquery.

```
   <script> 
        function addNewDivElement() {
            $("#parent_element").append('<div class = "child_element">')
        }
    </script>
```

the function `addNewDivElement` can be called on click of a button. something like below:

```
  <button onclick="addNewDivElement()"> 
        Add
  </button>
```